# How to make columns/item list the same size in a radio button list -

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have two radio list controls having - 5 list item for rach radio list and "RepeatDirection="Horizontal". the issue is i would like to make same size for itemlist so that the UI looks properly.

```
             <asp:RadioButtonList  
             ID="RadioButtonList1"  
             runat="server"  
             BorderWidth="2"  
             BorderColor="SaddleBrown"  
             BorderStyle="Dotted"  
             Font-Names="Comic Sans MS"  
             ForeColor="Snow"  
             BackColor="OrangeRed"  
             Width="400"                  
             RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
             >  
            <asp:ListItem Text="CornFlowerBlue"></asp:ListItem>  
            <asp:ListItem Text="Pink"></asp:ListItem>  
            <asp:ListItem Text="Orange"></asp:ListItem>  
            <asp:ListItem Text="DarkBlue"></asp:ListItem>  
            <asp:ListItem Text="DarkCyan"></asp:ListItem>  
        </asp:RadioButtonList>  
        <br />  

         <asp:RadioButtonList  
             ID="RadioButtonList2"  
             runat="server"  
             BorderWidth="2"  
             BorderColor="SaddleBrown"  
             BorderStyle="Dotted"  
             Font-Names="Comic Sans MS"  
             ForeColor="Snow"  
             BackColor="OrangeRed"  
             Width="400" 
             RepeatDirection="Horizontal"                 

             >  
            <asp:ListItem Text="Red"></asp:ListItem>  
            <asp:ListItem Text="Pink"></asp:ListItem>  
            <asp:ListItem Text="Orange"></asp:ListItem>  
            <asp:ListItem Text="DarkBlue"></asp:ListItem>  
            <asp:ListItem Text="white"></asp:ListItem>  
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

asp:RadioButtonList Creates a table on DOM, Here you can easily handle this with CSS

Add this code to header style tag.

#RadioButtonList2 td, #RadioButtonList1 td { min-width: 140px;}